# Which Database back end should I use for Faculty Feedback System for an Engineering College?

Tags: json, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm working on A Faculty Feedback System for an Engineering College that'll take feedback from the Students in Intranet.

Functions like,

1. Student will give feedback for individual faculty members of their respective class for their respective subject.
2. Students are divided in the batches like (A,B,C,D,E) for their practical purpose and individual feedback should also be there for respective Lab Faculties.
3. Subject Entry with respective Faculty needs to be stored prior to start taking feedback. So that can automatically retrieved for Student Feedback.
4. List of Questions is stored to display as feedback form to the student with some categories like (Excellent, Good, Okay, Poor) & when student submit his/her feedback, it need to be stored in the back end DB.

Now for all this, First i thought about the Document Structure based JSON DB and also figure out some structure by dividing Semester, Class, Lab, User, Student, Faculty, Admin, Feedback in the individual JSON nodes with individual entries/fields as below:

```
{
    Semester: { sem01: { name: "", year: "2017"}
    },
    Class: { class01: { name: "classo1", semid:"sem01"}
    },
    Lab :{ lab01 : {name : "labA", classid : "class01"}
    },
    User : { user01 :{ name : "faculty01", pwd: "****", role : "faculty"}
    },
    Faculty : { faculty01 : { userid : "user01",fname : "NAME", lname : "" }
    },
    Student : { student01 : { userid : "user02"}
    },
    Feedback : { feedbackid : { feedback : {}, user : "user02"}
    }
}
```

This is only on paper and thought about this idea.

I am confused how I'll store the Questions in this structures for each feedback. Or else I will move to use Table bases DB for whole system.

I any one have some idea, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the amount of data which is being involved in your use case , you can all the time go with relational database .

One should go with nosql , if there are large amount of joins or the data is huge to be incorporated in single machine . Sharding is implemented implicitly in nosql making it easy to shard the data when required .

For nosql , data needs to be stored , in a way such that data is in precomputed form .

So while creating structure for document based database , you need to consider =>

Areas where you can tolerate duplicate entries , but you want data in O(1). 
Like in your case , if we want data for teachers , we can store data in following way :-

```
{
  "name" : "xyz",
   "feedbacks":[
       "Q1":[
            {
              "cand1":"good",
              "cand2":"bad"
            }
         ],
       "Q2":[
            {
              "cand1":"good",
              "cand2":"bad"
            }
         ]
    ]
}
```

By storing data in this format , you can get data for teachers without referring to some other collection .

Same way you can store data for students . 
At the end , there would be redundant data but your retrieval process would be fast . 
So its like memory vs retrieval time trade off .